# Reputation by month page on Mathematica is wrong?

Tags: bug, reputation

The **reputation by month** page(s) on [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users) appear to be wrong.  Presently it looks like this:

[image]

According to the hover-over that is "2016-08-01 to today."

The **quarter** page, which is "2016-07-01 to today":

[image]

Observe that users [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs?tab=reputation&sort=graph), [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr?tab=reputation&sort=graph), [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods?tab=reputation&sort=graph), [Bob Halon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon?tab=reputation&sort=graph), [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens?tab=reputation&sort=graph), [Edmund](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19542/edmund?tab=reputation&sort=graph), and [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan?tab=reputation&sort=graph) have the same reputation on both pages.  This would indicate that these users gained no reputation for the entire month of July, but a review of the reputation pages will demonstrate that this is false.

Comment: Also on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332118/users-by-reputation-month-view-broken-again Looks like it's across sites, and some users' rep gain totals didn't reset for the start of August.

Comment: @Kendra Thanks.  I wish I had found that first as I could have saved myself a bit of time in preparing this question.